# Issues with Greek letters, bolding, and font packages

Tags: fonts, symbols, errors

I am trying to write an exam for multivariable calculus, with `\usepackage{bookman,eulervm}` and I am running into some very, very stange errors:

1. When I try to use `\mathbf{}` on a Greek letter (e.g. `\omega`), LaTeX complies the symbol as something completely different: `\mathbf{\omega}` ends up making a boldface exclamation point; `\mathbf{\tau}` appears as a boldface nullset; `\mathbf{\pi}` appears as a boldface Eszett; etc. When I remove the font `usepackage`, the Greek letters simply fail to bold, but remain unchanged.
2. Inside one particular `\begin{align*}` (nested inside a `\begin{enumerate}` environment) I have the line:

   > `&= (100\rm{rad}/\rm{sec})(20\rm{cm})(\sin(\pi/2))\\`

   and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the `\pi` is rendering as the german letter ß!

   [image]

   It is acting like it does when I try to make the `\pi` boldfaced (with the `bookman` and `eulervm` packages), yet is not bold?!

   Has anyone ever encountered this error before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the unexpected ess-zett shows up because `\rm` is not a command that takes an argument but, instead, a *switch*: all subsequent material (until either some other font-changing command is encountered or until the current (math) environment ends) is instructed to show up in "roman" mode. It just so happens that the text-mode glyph that's in the same spot of the respective font table where `\pi` would be in the math mode font table happens to be the ess-zett.

Rather than using `\rm` -- which is a holdover from (Plain) TeX and is only barely supported by LaTeX -- you really should use either the `\text` macro of the `amsmath` package (which you're already loading anyway, it would appear) and/or create a few dedicated macros, such as

```
\newcommand\rad{\text{rad}}  % `\text` is a macro provided by the amsmath package
\newcommand\second{\text{sec}}
\newcommand\cm{\text{cm}}
```

and then write

```
\begin{align*}
   &= (100\,\rad/\second)(20\,\cm)(\sin(\pi/2))
\end{align*}
```

which will give you the output you'd expect to get. (Aside: You should probably write "s" rather than "sec" for second...)

**Addendum** Better still, consider loading the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/) package, e.g., with the instruction

```
\usepackage[mode=text,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
```

(as well as, of course, the `amsmath`, `eulervm`, and `bookman` packages). Then you could write the expression in question as

```
\begin{align*}
   &= (\SI{100}{\radian\per\second})(\SI{20}{\centi\meter})(\sin(\pi/2))
\end{align*}
```

and you'd automatically get a proper "thin-space" between the numerals and the associate units.

Finally, you mention encountering some problems with `\mathbf`; that works for (Latin) letters but not for other symbols (including various Greek letters). Use `\boldsymbol` for the latter symbols.